# Solana CLI: Use an other Phantom address

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I configured Solana CLI with a wallet address and now I want to change it.

I did the following steps in order to swap to the new Phantom address I want to use :

```
$ solana-keygen recover 'prompt:?key=6/0' --outfile ~/.config/solana/id.json
```

then I inserted my seed phrase and finally I got this output :

> Recovered pubkey `Bw...35h`. Continue? (y/n): y
> Wrote recovered keypair to ~/.config/solana/id.json

which is exactly the address I want to use ! But then when I check using `solana address` or `solana-keygen pubkey` I keep getting the old address :

> solana-keygen pubkey
> 63...95x

> solana address
> 63...95x

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
   solana config set -k ~/.config/solana/keypair.json
```

Edit

Answer (score 0):

You can always check for Solana's current configuration using:

```
solana config get
```

After that check and make sure that the keypair your solana-cli is currently pointing to is actually the keypair you want in this case it might be pointing to the old keypair file

In order to change this use

```
solana config set --keypair <path_to_your_keypair>
```

For example

```
solana config set --keypair ~/.config/solana/id.json
```

I hope this helps!